# Static/shared property and method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, static-methods

I'm trying to have a 'class' in JS which tracks how many instances of itself have been instantiated. I am attempting to do so like this...

```
var myNamespace = {};

myNamespace.myClass = function () {
    //fails here as .getNetInstanceNo() not recognised...
    var instanceNumber = myNamespace.myClass.getNextInstanceNo();

    return {
        instanceNo : function() { return instanceNumber; }        
    }        
};

myNamespace.myClass.InstanceNo = 0; //static property?

//should the class itself have this method added to it...
myNamespace.myClass.prototype.getNextInstanceNo = function () { //static method?
  return myNamespace.myClass.InstanceNo++;  
};

var class1 = new myNamespace.myClass();

alert('class 1 has instance of ' + class1.instanceNo() );
```

However this fails as the `getNextInstanceNo` function is not recognised. Even though I think I'm adding it through the `myClass.prototype`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In can solve this by simply not adding the method to `.prototype` - but I thought this was pretty much what prototype was for?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`prototype` is an object from which other objects inherit properties, as in when you create an instance of an object and that object doesn't have a property/method, when called, the prototype of the class in which the object belongs to is searched for that property/method, here's a simple example:

```
function Animal(){};
Animal.prototype.Breathe = true;

var kitty= new Animal();
kitty.Breathe; // true (the prototype of kitty breathes)

var deadCat = new Animal();
deadCat.Breathe = false;
deadCat.Breathe; // false (the deadCat itself doesn't breath, even though the prototype does have breath
```

As you said yourself, you don't need to define getNextInstanceNo on prototype, since that's not how static methods are defined on JavaScript, leave it right right there on the class itself, instead you can define the `instanceNo` method on prototype, here's how:

```
var myNamespace = {};

myNamespace.myClass = function () {
    this.instanceNumber = myNamespace.myClass.getNextInstanceNo();
};

myNamespace.myClass.prototype.instanceNo = function () {
    return this.instanceNumber;
};

myNamespace.myClass.InstanceNo = 0; 

myNamespace.myClass.getNextInstanceNo = function () { 
    return myNamespace.myClass.InstanceNo++;
};

var class1 = new myNamespace.myClass();

alert('class 1 has instance of ' + class1.instanceNo());
```

Comment: So in my post where I say `var instanceNumber = myNamespace.myClass.getNextInstanceNo()` - what is it actually trying to do that it fails to do and why?